# Users cannot create quotes anymore

Tags: opportunity, quote

Yesterday evening users could create quotes from opportunities, but today they cannot anymore. Nothing has changed in our system, I can vouch for that. I checked incoming change sets, audit trail, nothing. Also, there are just two admins, and yesterday evening we haven't done anything.

The symptom is that no opportunity fields are copied to the New Quote screen, so you cannot save the quote.

[image]

I have already filed a case at Salesforce Support, I was wondering if other people have the same problem.

Update 1: the above "New Quote" button is the standard Salesforce button. Another user noted that a custom button, that uses a URL hack to fill fields when creating a new Account, also has the problem that fields are no longer filled. So there seems to be a wider problem where values from the URL are no longer copied to fields in the window.

Update 2: as an attempt for a workaround, I created a custom List button at the quote object with contents: `/lightning/o/Quote/new` and added it to the quote related list of an opportunity.

This pops up the new quote window, with empty fields of course, but just as in the earlier screenshot, there is no possibility to fill the name of the linked opportunity.

Update 3: this problem only happens in Lightning Experience. As an ultimate workaround, switch to Classic, create the quote there and switch back to Lightning.

Comment: you can refresh the owd for object set it as read/write both and then again check it out.

Comment: So your workaround is to set "Create Quotes Without a Related Opportunity" to true and let Sales add the missing Opportunity reference in an additional step manually for now?

Comment: I guess looking at the Chrome logs, opening the New Quote editor, you see this "LWC error": `Invalid id value "undefined". The id attribute must contain a non-empty string.`

Comment: I just got word from Salesforce Support: "An ongoing investigation is logged and the R&D team is currently investigating this issue. Our Multiple users are facing the same issues and here is the investigation number- W-14411976."

Comment: @FelixvanHove I do not have a workaround at this moment. I cannot even add a New Quote button anywhere. Trying to create an Action with Type "Create a Record" will not let me choose Quote, it's not listed in the picklist.

Comment: I meant: Setup - Feature Settings - Sales - Quotes - Quote Settings and there disabling the necessity to have an Opportunity at hand. Sales would need to add the Opp manually afterwards.

Comment: @FelixvanHove I had just turned it on, but Salesforce Support requested me to turn it off again. My bigger problem is that I cannot create a custom "New Quote" button, the system just won't let me. I should be able to create one on Opportunity, but see my earlier remark: it's impossible.

Comment: Does this also happen in classic?

Comment: @Swetha In Classic it works! There the opportunity name is filled!

Comment: On the one org (00D06000001b4xj), where I can reproduce this, - it does not happen in Classic, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a multi-customer issue. This has been posted on Trust https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/1220

> Issue: The Salesforce Technology team noted a feature degradation impacting multiple instances within the Salesforce production environment. The Technology team noted a recent release to be the potential trigger of the issue and decided to roll back the release on one of the impacted instances to see if that helps in resolving the issue.

> Impact: Customers are experiencing issues when creating child records from a related list of parent object in the User interface (UI) wherein the parent object details are not being populated, preventing them from saving the record.